# show TabBarConroller with storyboard programmatically

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I'm using the storyboard for my application.

```
- (IBAction)LogInButtonClicked:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"clicked");


[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:_mailAddressTextField.text password:_passwordTextField.text
                                block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                    if (user) {
                                        NSLog(@"Login correct");
                                        // show tabBarConroller
                                    } else {
                                        [self showAlertwithMesage];
                                    }
                                }];
```

}

How can I show my tabBarController from the storyboard if the login is correct?
If I add a segue to the Loginbutton, the tabBarConroller will be showed allways.
But i want to show the tabBarConroller if the login is correct

The solution i found till now doesn't solved my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign storyboard Id to your `TabBarController` in your storyboard.
Present tab bar when login is successful.

```
UITabBarController *myController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourStoryBoardID"];
[self presentViewController:myController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgott to assign the storyboard id.